# Parsing XML GPO report obtained via Get-GPResultantSetofPolicy

Tags: xml, powershell, active-directory, group-policy

I managed to use Get-GPOReport to export the config for a specific GPO to XML and then use PowerShell to navigate through it to find the User Rights Assignments.

I'm trying to do something similar with the RSOP data using Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy

```
Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy -computer localhost -ReportType Xml -path "C:\temp\RSOP.xml"
[xml]$Xml = gc "C:\temp\RSOP.xml"
$xml.rsop.ComputerResults.ExtensionData.extension
```

The third line gives me the results below, but from here I'm lost as to how to obtain the User Rights Assignments.

[image]

If I import the XML into XML Notepad it shows the following:
[image]

I want to filter out everything apart from the the 5 Deny privileges (SeDenyNetworkLogonRight, SeDenyBatchLogonRight, SeDenyServiceLogonRight, SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight, SeDenyRemoteInteractiveLogonRight) and get the name of the accounts which are given this privilege (e.g. Guests and SERVICE)

Comment: Why not just use the PowerShell *xml* cmdlets or the Net namespaces for XML? See the PowerShell help files for details and examples. Parsing text, Json, XML files is a very common daily thing with PowerShell. There are tons of articles, blogs, MS Docs, Youtube videos, and Q&A's right here on SO. Just search the web, Youtube, [or use the SO search box above to find them](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D+Get-GPOReport+parse).

Answer (score 0):

How about leveraging any of the following modules from the MS powershellgallery.com to help with your use case, vs parsing that report directly?

```
Find-Module -Name '*gpo*'
```

or

```
Find-Module -Name '*userrights*'
```

or

```
Find-Module -Name '*privil*'
```

Or something like this to get only what you want:

```
$String = 'SeDenyNetworkLogonRight|SeDenyBatchLogonRight|SeDenyServiceLogonRight'
$Domain = $env:USERDNSDOMAIN

$NearestDC = (Get-ADDomainController -Discover -NextClosestSite).Name

#Get a list of GPOs from the domain
Get-GPO -All -Domain $Domain -Server $NearestDC | 
Sort-Object DisplayName | 
#Go through each Object and check its XML against $String
Foreach {
  Write-Host "Working on $($PSItem.DisplayName)"

  #Get Current GPO Report (XML)
  $CurrentGPOReport = Get-GPOReport -Guid $PSItem.Id -ReportType Xml -Domain $Domain -Server $NearestDC

  If ($CurrentGPOReport -match $String)  {
    Write-Host "A Group Policy matching ""$($String)"" has been found:" -Foregroundcolor Green
    Write-Host "-  GPO Name: $($PSItem.DisplayName)" -Foregroundcolor Green
    Write-Host "-  GPO Id: $($PSItem.Id)" -Foregroundcolor Green
    Write-Host "-  GPO Status: $($PSItem.GpoStatus)" -Foregroundcolor Green
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml.rsop.ComputerResults.ExtensionData.extension.userrightsassignment | ? name -like "*deny*" | select name, @{label='entity';expression={$_.member.name.'#text'}}
```